# Emissions in the gamma ray frequency from gamma ray burst

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, astrophysics, astronomy, gamma-rays

Since almost all the emissions detected from gamma-ray burst are from its afterglow which are not in the gamma-ray frequency.  Is the afterglow emission frequency lower than gamma-ray frequency ? I would like to know whether or not the GRB emission has been detected in the gamma-ray frequency.

Comment: Can you rewrite your question - at the moment it looks like you are asking whether a Gamma Ray Burst source emits gamma rays.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear [from this review article t](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma-ray_burst)hat they are called gamma ray bursts because of the detection of gamma radiation at the initial stage.

> " After an initial flash of gamma rays, a longer-lived "afterglow" is usually emitted at longer wavelengths (X-ray, ultraviolet, optical, infrared, microwave and radio)."

Answer (score 0):

For three decades, from the 1960's to the 1990's, we *only* knew of this phenomenon from gamma-ray observations. We didn't have a clear idea of what they were. Most hypotheses predicted some sort of afterglow, but the nature of the afterglow was different for different hypotheses, so we didn't have a clear idea what to look for. For a long time, we hardly know where GRBs were coming from. To find the afterglows, it took the development of spacecraft ([BeppoSax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeppoSAX), [HETE-2](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/hete2/hete2.html), and [Swift](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/heasarc/missions/swift.html)) specifically designed to find and disseminate their locations quickly. Afterglows are faint, difficult to find unless you know exactly where to look.